# Bizarre HTTP 500 Server Error: when using h2o's import_file

Tags: python, import, h2o, http-status-code-500

I have a large csv I am trying to read into h2o and train a model based on. When h2o is parsing the large csv though my program keeps crashing and giving me this strange http 500 error that I am not sure how to interpret.

The line of code that causes the crash is:

```
data = h2o.import_file("data/Data_Labeled.csv", col_types=col_types)
```

But when the code runs and gets to this line it looks like it almost completes parsing the file and then crashes with the following trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "vairal.py", line 12, in <module>
bb.train_model()
File "/Users/mark/Desktop/vairal/vairal/reddit_model.py", line 15, in train_model
data = h2o.import_file("data/Data_Labeled.csv", col_types=col_types)
...
File "/Users/mark/Downloads/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.py", line 730, in _process_response
raise H2OServerError("HTTP %d %s:\n%r" % (status_code, response.reason, data))
h2o.exceptions.H2OServerError: HTTP 500 Server Error:
u'<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>\n<title>Error 500 Server Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h2>HTTP ERROR: 500</h2>\n<p>Problem accessing /3/Frames/Reddit_Data_Labeled.hex. Reason:\n<pre>    Server Error</pre></p>\n<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>\n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n</body>\n</html>\n'
```

I have 0 idea what this means and would love some context. I can't tell if the formating of the csv is bad somewhere or if maybe it's just crashing because my computer can't handle the parse- either way the crash message seems unhelpful to me.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: I think this had something to do with the max_mem_size parameter I was passing into h2o.init

Comment: You need to look at the stdout and stderr log files.  The names for these are printed out when calling h2o.init().  Not giving it enough memory is very likely to cause this.

Comment: Showing the output of `h2o.init()` is helpful for troubleshooting, especially number of nodes, number of cores and the memory (but it is also useful to show the h2o version, python version, etc.).  (BTW, if you've solved your problem, can you self-answer?)